# qt ASSERT failure in QList<T>::at: "index out of range"

Tags: c++, qt, runtime-error

I am still relatively new to Qt and I have recently been working on a large project. When I attempt to run the project I get this error:

```
ASSERT failure in QList<T>::at: "index out of range", file c:\qt\qt5.3.0\5.3\msvc2013_64\include\qtcore\qlist.h, line 479
```

Just wondering if anyone knows what this means or how I might go about tracking down the source of the problem?

[edit] I believe that the addition of this code is causing the error

```
autAtom *aP = new autAtom(Principal);
    autAtom *aQ = new autAtom(Principal);

    autData *P = new autData (DataAtom, aP);
    autData *Q = new autData (DataAtom, aQ);
    autData *X = new autData (AnyData);

    AUTPostulate *p;
    autStatementList preList;


    {
        preList.clear();
        //autData *d1 = new autData(NotHereData, X);
        autStatement *pre1 = new autStatement(aP, believes, X);
        autStatement *goal = new autStatement(aP, sees, X);
        preList.append(pre1);
        p = new AUTPostulate("BS", BS, goal, preList);
        cout << "" << p->getString().toStdString() << endl;
        AUTPostulates.append(p);

    }
```

When this is taken out the tool runs fine.

Comment: Tracking the source of the problem consists in reading the error message : you are trying to access an element at an index which is out of bounds. ie you have a bug.

Comment: If you work your way up the stacktrace of the error, it should be quite simple to fix. In my opinion the error message is quite clear in what's wrong, and there is little room for interpretation.

Comment: I hope you plan on freeing all of that dynamically allocated memory. Oh, and freeing it properly if an exception is thrown anywhere.

Comment: chris means that you really should never use naked pointers for resource management. Use a `QScopedPointer`/`std::unique_ptr`, or `QSharedPointer`/`std::shared_ptr` depending on what you need. But **never** use `std::auto_ptr` -- it's broken by design, horribly so.

Comment: @chris It's quite possible that code uses Qt-style object ownership model, so the `Principal` object owns the `autAtom` objects, which own the `autData` objects. Additionally, Qt application code doesn't normally use exceptions, and when it does, they must be caught by application code before they propagate to Qt event loop.

Answer (score 7):

I ran into a similar issue because I did a `connect` on `itemChanged` before populating the widget and then while populating my slot code was called. After I put in a guard that prevented signal handling during widget population, I found I could populate the widget fine and I could also handle the signal fine after. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you!! The exact same thing was happenign to me but I didn't piece it together until I saw you answer!! You have no Idea the trouble you've just saved me!!!

Comment: Thanks, I have done a quick fix by adding connect in constructor.

Answer (score 1):

Index out of range means you're trying to access an index of a QList object, or maybe an object that is a subclass of a QList that does not exist. So if you have a QList with a length of 5 and you try to access index 5, it will be out of range.

Also, it looks like your code contains a lot of classes that are not standard to Qt or C++. At least I don't recognize them. It's difficult to say what's going on here without knowing about those classes.